# How to upgrade my VS project from Silverlight 3 to version 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

How do I upgrade my Visual Studio 2010 project from Silverlight 3 to Silverlight 4?  When I choose the properties for my project and then choose the "Silverlight" tab I can see that I have a drop-down menu to change the "Target Silverlight Version" but I only have a "Silverlight 3" option.

Thanks for answering a noob question,

Comment: Do you have the Silverlight 4.0 SDK installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Silverlight 4.0 SDK and the properties will include Silverlight 4.

**UPDATE:**
As the comment says below, to get the Silverlight 4 option, install Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Will I still have v3 available?  I have another project that is using v3 and I have another test solution that I'd like to use with v4.

Comment: Both versions will continue to function side-by-side.  That's why you're able to set the version in the project, so you can support both versions.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Also, for the sake of completeness, for VS 2010, one should also install "Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010".